# How to avoid the Axiom of Choice in proving Higman's Lemma?

Tags: axiom-of-choice, proof-explanation

In [this paper](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/LongFinSeq98-2f0wmq3.pdf) (pp 2-3) Friedman proves a version of [Higman's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma) for infinite sequences of finite words on a finite alphabet. Such a sequence $S$ is called "bad" if no element of $S$ occurs as a subsequence in a later element of $S$. (E.g., a sequence that contains $\dots,oar,\dots,foobar,\dots$ is *not* bad, because $oar$ occurs as a subsequence in the later word $foobar$.)

The proof begins by supposing (for the sake of contradiction) that there exists at least one bad sequence, then it constructs a so-called "minimal bad sequence" $y_1,y_2,y_3,\dots$ as follows:

- Choose $y_1$ to be a shortest word that starts some bad sequence, then
- choose $y_2$ to be a shortest word such that $y_1,y_2$ starts some bad sequence, then
- choose $y_3$ to be a shortest word such that $y_1,y_2,y_3$ starts some bad sequence, then
- etc.

This would seem to be an evident use of the AoC, and the proof continues after merely remarking parenthetically that *"The axiom of choice can be eliminated in an obvious way."*

> **Question**:  In what "obvious way" can the AoC be eliminated from this proof? How can a (hypothetical) minimal bad sequence be constructed without the AoC?

Comment: on the alphabet $A$, starting from $a_0 \in A$, if at each step you have to choose $a_{n+1} \ne a_{n}$ such that $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ then in a finite number of steps you'll reach one of the minimal elements, those which are not $\ge$ than all the other elements of $A$, and the sequence will stop there. obviously, starting with a word $s_0$ on $A$, if at every step you can remove one or more letters or "decrease" a letter as previously, you'll reach in a finite number of steps the empty word $\implies$ there is no infinite "bad" (decreasing) sequence on $S$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need AC to prove that the set of all finite words on a finite alphabet is a countable set. Fix an enumeration of the set of all finite words. Whenever you have to choose an element from a nonempty set of words, choose the one that comes first in the enumeration.

Comment: Finally! You post something as an answer and not as a comment! :)